# Simple Subalgebras of Simple Lie Algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras

Given a complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of rank $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n$ sufficiently large (say $n\ge10$), is there a way to determine whether $\mathfrak{g}$ contains a simple subalgebra of a prescribed type with rank "close" to $n$? For example, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is of type $B_n$ with $n\ge10$, does $\mathfrak{g}$ contain a subalgebra of type $C_{n-2}$?

Comment: Some more tags are natural here, such as rt.representation-theory.   Many of us rely on the tags to identify questions which may be interesting.   (Also, it's useful to highlight the basic question being asked with > followed by space.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the question in your example is no in general: $B_n$ does not contain $C_{n-2}$ for large $n$. To see this, observe that $B_n$ has an irreducible orthogonal representation $V$ of dimension $2n+1$. The Weyl dimension formula shows that for any simple Lie algebra, the dimension of an irreducible representation is the smallest for fundamental representations.

[Edited]

For large $n$, the smallest dimensional fundamental representation of $C_{n-2}$ is the standard one, of dimension $2n-4$. 
Therefore  the restriction of $V$ to $C_{n-2}$ can only be some copies of the trivial representation and ONE copy of the standard representation $W$ of dimension $2n-4$. This means that the group of type $C_{n-2}$ must preserve both a symplectic form and a quadratic form on $W$, which is impossible by Schur's lemma.  Hence  the restriction of $V$ to $C_{n-2}$ can only be a sum of copies of the trivial representation which is 
impossible.

I had previously given a wrong reason (assuming that the rep of $B_n$ had dimension $n$; thanks to @BS for pointing this out.

Comment: I thought $B_n$ was $so(2n+1)$. What is its $n$-dim irrep ?

Comment: Thank you. You are right (I had a brain fade). I have given the correct reason now, I hope.

Comment: Schur's lemma usually refers to the statement that the space of equivariant endomorphisms of an irreducible representation is one-dimensional. How does that implies that $C_{n-2}$ cannot preserve two binary forms?

Comment: The existence of an invariant Bilinear form on W gives an equivariant map between W and it’s dual. By Schur’s lemme, there is only one such up to scalars

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but there have been some classic works, developing general methods for such topics:

- In [Dynkin, Semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras, Mat. Sb. (N.S.), 1952,    Volume 30(72),  Number 2, p. 349–462](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5435&option_lang=eng), the author -among others- classifies (up to linear equivalence) the simple Lie subalgebras of the Lie algebras of exceptional type. The original paper is in Russian (and is free) but you can find a translation in the translation series of AMS [here](https://www.ams.org/books/trans2/006/) (not free). Some of these results have been refined and generalized in a 2006 paper by Minchenko (but i do not have available the exact reference right now),
- In [M. Lorente, B. Gruber, Classification of Semisimple Subalgebras of Simple Lie Algebras, Journal of Mathematical Physics 13, 1639 (1972)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1665888), the authors extend Dynkin's methods and classify the simple subalgebras of Lie algebras of classical type of rank $\leq 6$, up to linear equivalence,
- In [W. A.de Graaf, Constructing semisimple subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras, Journal of Algebra, v. 325, 1, 2011, p.416-430](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186931000534X?via%3Dihub), general methods are obtained for classifying the semisimple subalgebras of a given semisimple Lie algebra, up to linear equivalence. Some of these methods are then applied to obtain a classification of the semisimple subalgebras of the simple Lie algebras of rank $\leq 8$.

Answer (score 4):

Simple algebras of rank >8 are classical, so you are asking is there a representation (linear, orthogonal or symplectic) of a given dimension of a prescribed Lie algebra. This amounts to the question what is the minimal dimension of a nontrivial linear, orthogonal or symplectic representation of the Lie algebra. A table in Bourbaki answers this.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the location of the "table in Bourbaki"?

Comment: Tables I and II in "Groupes et algèbres de Lie, Chapitres 7 et 8" (I use Russian translation but I hope the tables are in the original text as well and not added by a translator).

Comment: Since my copy is the first printing of the French edition, I can confirm that these tables occur at the end of the text of Chapter 8 before the exercises.   (There is an obvious misprint $F_6$ for $E_6$ in Table II.)    Note however that the tables claim only to provide data for the fundamental representations in each Lie type.

Comment: The table in Bourbaki yields the fundamental reps, their dimension, and say if they are orthogonal, symplectic, or none. If $V$ is any rep of dimension $d$, then $V\oplus V$ can be made both orthogonal and symplectic. So how do we conclude? the issue is that possibly, if there's a $d$-dimensional rep, are there non-fundamental irreducibles of dimensions $<2d$? is there a way to list them, and know if they're orthogonal/symplectic?

Comment: For the last part of the question, Proposition 12 in Chapter 8 of Bourbaki gives a nice criterion to be orthogonal or symplectic in terms of the coordinates of the highest weight of a representation. The dimension, as mentioned above, can be computed via the Weyl dimension formula. But I don't know an explicit procedure how to list all representations of dimension less than a given bound.